# Об истории мягкого знака после шипящих на конце существительных

Tags: мягкий-знак

В русском языке  все сущ.  3-го скл.  ж.р. имеют мягкую основу (тень,  медь, пыль), в то время как  сущ. 2-го  скл. м.р. могут иметь как твердую основу (стол, сад), так и мягкую (конь, голубь, гвоздь, гусь, зверь). Таким образом, мягкий знак на конце существительного не является показателем рода, но тогда почему он стал показателем  ж.р. после шипящих?

Какова история написания, к примеру, слова м.р. «мечь» (кажется, изначально там писался мягкий знак)? Как и когда появилась идея грамматических знаков (твердого и мягкого) для обозначения рода?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь действует ПРИНЦИП ГРАФИКО-МОРФОЛОГИЧЕСКИХ АНАЛОГИЙ

Это название может быть применено к принципу написания буквы ь после шипящих в ряде морфологических категорий: буква ь может быть рассматриваема как графический уравнитель парадигм склонения существительных типа ночь, рожь (как ель) и как графический уравнитель морфологических категорий повелительного наклонения: режь (как брось), а также инфинитива: беречь(как брать).

Традиционно считается, что написание буквы ь выполняет функцию грамматического сигнала: **буква ь сигнализирует о женском роде слов ночь, рожь и т.д.**

Однако "сигнализирующая функция" буквы ь в определенных категориях слов - это лишь следствие, а не причина его употребления. Причиной является ***влияние определенных графико-морфологических моделей, т.е. морфологическая аналогия***. Слова женского рода типа рожь, ночь дают одинаковую графическую парадигму склонения со словами типа дверь (ср.: д**верь - дверью, рожь - рожью, ночь - ночью**), в то время как слова мужского рода типа врач, шалаш имеют такую же графическую парадигму, как и слова типа стол (ср.: **стол - столом, врач - врачом, шалаш - шалашом**).

При распределении слов по типам склонения употребление буквы ь после шипящих в качестве ведущего признака родового значения слов в русских грамматиках обычно не учитывается. К третьему склонению относят существительные женского рода с "основой на мягкие согласные и на шипящие ж и ш"

Однако то, что буква ь создает графическое единообразие парадигм склонения, учитывается как ведущий признак при подаче этого материала нерусским.
Так, в частности, в кратком очерке русской грамматики, предназначенном для французов, А.А. Зализняк выделяет **как относящиеся к одному типу склонения имена существительные, имеющие в форме именительного падежа единственного числа букву ь**. Подобную же Написание же буквы ь в словах типа дочь, мышь не является этимологическим и по происхождению (об этом свидетельствует ненаписание буквы ь в словах типа врач, нож).

В древнерусском языке в соответствующих грамматических формах **после всех шипящих, поскольку они были исконно мягкими, писался "ерь" (т.е. ь как знак редуцированного гласного переднего ряда). Писалось не только дочь, ночь, мышь, но и врачь, ножь, мужь и т.п. Однако со временем, после отвердения /ж/ и /ш/ и исчезновения редуцированных гласных, эти написания "сбились".** После ж и ш начинают употреблять не только ь, но и ъ. В "Российской грамматике" Ломоносова представлены написания: речь, дочь, ключь, мечь, но ковшъ, ножъ.

В "Материалах к Российской грамматике" у Ломоносова намечается разделение написаний ь и ъ после шипящих по родам. Так, он дает вещь, но лещъ, таковы же соотношения между написаниями мышь и ковшъ

Намеченное Ломоносовым разделение его ученик и последователь В. Светов обобщил в правило. Причем В. Светов уже подчеркивал графико-морфологическую целесообразность этого правила: "Имена на ь кончающиеся мужского рода в родительном удерживают на конце я; из чего явственно, что не право пишется ключь, товарищь, врачь; ибо в родительном не ключя, товарищя и не врачя. Надобно писать: ключъ, товарищъ, врачъ, в родительном ключа, товарища, врача и так другие"

Правило, требующее не писать после шипящих мягкий знак в словах мужского рода (и писать его в словах женского рода), как "легкое", было поддержано Сумароковым

Орфографическая практика закрепила это правило.
С отменой в 1917 - 1918 гг. буквы ъ на конце слов правило автоматически приняло современный вид (употребление буквы ь в словах женского рода на шипящие и неупотребление в словах мужского рода на шипящие).

Графическое противопоставление слов типа ночь, рожь словам типа врач, нож было введено сознательно на основе графико-морфологических аналогий. А.А. Реформатский справедливо пишет: "То, что в таких написаниях дело не в этимологии, показывают примеры иноязычных слов, на которые распространяется данное правило (фальшь, тушь, ср.: туш мужского рода без ь)"

В тех случаях, когда принадлежность того или иного слова к грамматическому роду неизвестна, **мягкий знак является полезным сигналом, так как, будучи употреблен в конце слов на шипящие, он сигнализирует о том, что перед нами слово женского рода и что изменять его нужно по третьему склонению**. Ср., например, такие названия, как река Оредеж, город Россошь, поселок Будогощь. Если увидеть их написанными, то мягкий знак даст нам понять, что слова Россошь и Будогощь женского рода, а Оредеж - мужского. Родовая же принадлежность слов с конечными согласными определяет и их тип склонения.
Полезен этот грамматический сигнал и для стабилизации родовой принадлежности слов на шипящие. Он удерживает их от родовых колебаний, которые часто "тревожат" слова с конечным мягким согласным. Слова с конечным мягким согласным могут быть женского (трость, ткань, тень, соль, роль, метель и т.п.) и мужского рода (олень, руль, уголь, грифель и т.п.). Одинаковость формальной приметы приводит к родовым колебаниям, а следовательно, и к колебаниям в склонении. В XIX в. колебался род существительных полынь, студень, ступень и др.; заимствованные слова акварель, вуаль, госпиталь, дуэль, карусель, мигрень, модель, патруль, рояль, тюль и др. были иными по своему родовому значению, чем сейчас.

наблюдаются колебания в роде некоторых существительных с основой на мягкий согласный, например, слов мозоль, выхухоль, картофель, толь и др. Поэтому определение рода (а следовательно, и типа склонения) таких существительных требует наведения справок в словарях.

С чисто звуковой точки зрения употребление мягкого знака после шипящих в словах женского рода является избыточным: и без него конечные /ч/ и /щ/ (Будогощь, ночь, мощь) произносились бы мягко, как произносятся они в словах ключ, плющ, а в словахРоссошь, рожь с чисто звуковой точки зрения написание мягкого знака иногда даже вредно, так как, например, при изучении русского языка в условиях диалекта может натолкнуть на неправильное мягкое произношение твердых /ш/ и /ж/.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Я не буду спорить с Людмилой, но есть прямой ответ на прямой вопрос.

> Таким образом, мягкий знак на конце существительного не является показателем рода, но тогда почему он стал показателем ж.р. после шипящих?

Именно потому, что после шипящих в русском языке **Ь** не может являться показателем смягчения. Все шипящие (включая аффрикаты) в русском не разделяются по твердости-мягкости. Ж, Ш и Ц в современном русском всегда твердые, Ч и Щ - всегда мягкие. Так почему же Ерю не найти другую, вполне посильную ему работу - стать показателем рода именно после шипящих? Ну а в других случаях у него есть прямые обязанности, как Вы верно пишете.

> Какова история написания, к примеру, слова м.р. «мечь» (кажется, изначально там писался мягкий знак)?

Да, но очень давно. В те времена, когда представление о противопоставлении шипящих по твердости-мягкости еще не сложилось, "мечь" писался с ерем как графический рефлекс древнего сверхкраткого. Не знаю точно времени (думаю, что раньше упоминаемого Любмилой Ломоносова), от этой практики отошли.

> Как и когда появилась идея грамматических знаков (твердого и мягкого) для обозначения рода?

А это уже у Людмилы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ